# Linear independence over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for varying primes

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in \mathbb{F}_p^n$ be a set of vectors, where $p$ is a prime. Assume further that the components of each vector can be represented by integers smaller than some integer $k$. Is there a way to check linear independence, so that it will be guaranteed for all primes larger than some concrete computable limit? For example, if we have linear independence over $\mathbb{Q}$, then my understanding is that this will hold for large enough $p$, but I don't know of any way of determining if a prime is large enough.

To simplify this problem maybe a bit, we could assume that all the components of the $v_i$'s are one of $-1,0,1$.

Any pointers on material regarding this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat better than the answer by Magdiragdag, which depends on choosing complementary vectors, you can proceed as follows. Take the matrix whose columns are your integer vectors, and compute its [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) over$~\Bbb Z$. If you get any zero entries on the main diagonal, then your vectors are linearly dependent over$~\Bbb Z$ and will remain so when reducing modulo any prime. If you do not get any zeros, then the final (largest) diagonal entry is such that its prime divisors$~p$ are precisely the primes for which reducing the vectors modulo$~p$ gives a linearly dependent family. (Note that if $k\neq n$, then the final diagonal entry is not the one in the lower right-hand corner).

That the above is true can be seen from the fact that the Smith normal form computation amounts to performing a base change over$~\Bbb Z$ (invertible by definition) such that the subgroup spanned by your given vectors is spanned by multiples (given by the diagonal entries) of the new basis vectors.

Comment: Agreed, this is nicer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a set of vectors (over ${\mathbb Z}$) that are linearly independent (over ${\mathbb Q}$), then you can extend them (with vectors over ${\mathbb Z}$) to a basis. The determinant of the matrix formed by this basis is a non-zero integer. For all primes $p$ that do not divide this determinant, your set of vectors will also be linearly independent over ${\mathbb F}_p$.